# Как узнать что размер окна был изменён tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

как можно определить событие, изменения размера окна?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

root.geometry('1920x1080')


def callback():
    if panel['image'] == 'img':
        img2 = (Image.open(r'Image\ActiveAppsDeveloper.png'))
        img2 = img2.resize((200, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
        panel.configure(image=img2)
        panel.image = img2
    else:
        img = (Image.open(r'Image\ActiveGamesButton.png'))
        rx = int(root.winfo_width() // 19.2)
        rx = int(327 / 100 * rx // 1)
        ry = int(root.winfo_height() // 10.8)
        ry = int(48 / 100 * ry // 1)
        img = img.resize((rx, ry), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        panel.configure(image=img)
        panel.image = img


img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'Image\ActiveGamesButton.png'))
panel = Button(root, image=img,  command=callback)
panel.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.update()

print(root.winfo_width())
print(root.winfo_height())

root.bind("WM_CONFIGURE", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто используйте `<Confiure>` вместо `WM_CONFIGURE`

```py
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    
    root = Tk()
    
    root.geometry('1920x1080')
    
    
    def callback():
        if panel['image'] == 'img':
            img2 = (Image.open(r'Image\ActiveAppsDeveloper.png'))
            img2 = img2.resize((200, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
            panel.configure(image=img2)
            panel.image = img2
        else:
            img = (Image.open(r'Image\ActiveGamesButton.png'))
            rx = int(root.winfo_width() // 19.2)
            rx = int(327 / 100 * rx // 1)
            ry = int(root.winfo_height() // 10.8)
            ry = int(48 / 100 * ry // 1)
            img = img.resize((rx, ry), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            panel.configure(image=img)
            panel.image = img
    
    
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'Image\ActiveGamesButton.png'))
    panel = Button(root, image=img,  command=callback)
    panel.grid(row=1, column=1)
    
    root.update()
    
    print(root.winfo_width())
    print(root.winfo_height())
    
    root.bind("<Configure>", callback)
    
    root.mainloop()
```